# Python - Test For Error

Tags: python, error-handling

In my program, It sometimes encounters an error. The only way to stop the error, is to restart the program.

So how could I get python to know when there is an error?

Example - If there is an error, close down the program.

How do I do this - Thanks!

Comment: There is a construct called [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) in python...

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll look it up! I wasn't sure if there was a programming term for it :D

Comment: You can call `import sys; sys.exit()` when there is a specific exception

Comment: Yes, that is what I was going to do, but I didn't know how to do the `if error` part. thanks- I've got it now :D

Comment: How are there 'too many answers', there is only 1 answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called **exception handling**. You should [read](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) about it.

The basic syntax is the following:

```
try:
    code that might give an error (aka exception)
except TheExceptionExpected:
    thing to do if error happends
```

Comment: How do I except ANY Error: for example

Comment: `try` (code)  - then `except (any error)`?

Comment: To except ANY error just use the widest exception whitch is "Exception" (upper case first letter). It is generaly not recommanded to do that because it is much harder to debug rather than using just the specific exceptions you know could happend.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll use it :D

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory ;)

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot - I'll accept it for you :D - I also dont know why I keep using that face either...